# Switch a buffer after C-x C-b command USING KEYBOARD

Tags: emacs, command, buffer

After having typed C-x C-b there will a new window showing currently opened buffers... that is easy. But how can I switch to one of them using only my keyboard? Now I have to move my mouse an click on the one of my interest, and that looks stupid:(

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's a standard read-only buffer with some special bindings. Switch to the window first with `C-x o`, then you can browse buffers with `n`, `p`. Open one in the new window with `RET`. You can even search the buffer if desired.

Answer (score 0):

Check [ido mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings). Actually similar questions have been asked quite a few time.